# Install Ubuntu without Setup

Tags: system-installation, configuration

I'm trying to create an Ubuntu install script which will install Ubuntu onto a machine such that, at next boot, the user will be prompted to perform the normal setup tasks such as picking a system language, username, password, etc, much like when you buy a new Mac or PC (and, I presume, a new laptop with pre-installed Ubuntu, although I've never done that, so I'm not sure).

Are there utilities or installation options which make this possible? If not, any ideas on how I might tackle this? I don't need explicit code, just some ideas to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called an OEM install, and it is covered on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for might be *preseeds* to install your system without asking questions, and then you can boot in your computer.
You have documentation here about that: 
https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apb.html.en
And you have here examples of a script on Github, that does that :
https://github.com/hvanderlaan/ubuntu-unattended
You can of course implement after the install you script, by adding it one way or another into the preseed.